# centering and superimposing numpy arrays efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have RGBA image data represented in two 3-dimensional `uint8` numpy arrays.  I want to center one of them (`image`) within the other (`canvas`).  The width and height of `image` will usually be smaller than the corresponding dimensions of `canvas`,  but they *may* be larger---in which case, a central section of `image` will be used and will completely obscure `canvas`.  In all cases the output will be the size and shape of `canvas`.

I can do this without error, but am surprised how unpythonically monstrous the code ended up:

```
h, w = canvas.shape[ :2 ]    # canvas.shape is [ h, w, 4 ] because it is an RGBA image
ih, iw = image.shape[ :2 ]   # image.shape is [ ih, iw, 4 ] because it is an RGBA image
xoffset = ( w - iw ) / 2.0
yoffset = ( h - ih ) / 2.0
xoffset = [ int( math.ceil( xoffset ) ), int( math.floor( xoffset ) ) ] # how much free space left and right
yoffset = [ int( math.ceil( yoffset ) ), int( math.floor( yoffset ) ) ] # how much free space top and bottom
if xoffset[ 0 ] < 0:
    image = image[ :, -xoffset[ 0 ]:, : ]
    iw += xoffset[ 0 ]
    xoffset[ 0 ] = 0
if xoffset[ 1 ] < 0:
    image = image[ :, :xoffset[ 1 ],  : ]
    iw += xoffset[ 1 ]
    xoffset[ 1 ] = 0
if yoffset[ 0 ] < 0:
    image = image[ -yoffset[ 0 ]:, :, : ]
    ih += yoffset[ 0 ]
    yoffset[ 0 ] = 0
if yoffset[ 1 ] < 0:
    image = image[ :yoffset[ 1 ],  :, : ]
    ih += yoffset[ 1 ]
    yoffset[ 1 ] = 0
canvas[ yoffset[ 0 ]:yoffset[ 0 ] + ih, xoffset[ 0 ]:xoffset[ 0 ] + iw, : ] = image
```

Can you see a more elegant/readable/maintainable way to do this? There has to be  a better solution than mine. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that `numpy` contains some functionality whose name I haven't been able to guess yet, but which can do it in one line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simplify this by realizing that the logic along each dimension is the same, so you can write a single function that will handle each dimension and output the appropriate array slices. Then you call this on both dimensions and apply the slices to the arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def get_slices_1D(canvas_size, image_size):
    buffer = abs(canvas_size - image_size) // 2
    if canvas_size > image_size:
        return slice(buffer, buffer + image_size), slice(None)
    else:
        return slice(None), slice(buffer, buffer + canvas_size)

def get_slices_ND(canvas_shape, image_shape):
    pairs = zip(canvas_shape, image_shape)
    return zip(*(get_slices_1D(*pair) for pair in pairs))
```

Now let's test it out:

```
image = np.ones((3, 7, 4))
canvas = np.zeros((5, 5, 4))

ind_can, ind_im = get_slices_ND(canvas.shape, image.shape)
canvas[ind_can] = image[ind_im]

canvas[:, :, 0]
# array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

As a bonus, this approach generalizes to arrays of any number of dimensions!

Comment: That is certainly neater.  The key insight I was missing is that very similarly computed slices can be used on **both** sides of the assignment.  I still wouldn't be surprised if there was a native `numpy` one-liner.